# FullCalendar dayClick does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I want to add the dayClick function to my fullCalendar.

The calendar appears correctly, but when I click on a day, nothing happens.

This is my code :

```
var calendar;

$(document).ready(function(){
    app.init();

    calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'basicWeek',
        firstDay: 1,
        weekends: false,
        weekNumbers: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next,today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view){
            console.log("Test");
            alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

            alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

            alert('Current view: ' + view.name);
        }
    });

    app.radioButton();
});
```

Other commands like firstDay, weekNumbers etc, are working correctly, and nothing is in the console.

This is a screenshot of my calendar, it doesn't look normal :

[fullCalendar screenshot](http://hpics.li/2a8c6e6)

What's wrong here ?

Comment: My guess is your `app.init();` The rest of the code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/wd0ym13s/

Comment: No, nothing in the console...

Comment: @Slyvain Ok, I will try to put this line after the fullCalendar line

Comment: Do you have other plugins loaded that can catch the event?

Comment: Still nothing... I think it's my css code, because my calendar doesn't look like your jsfiddle @Slyvain

Comment: @JordanThiervoz can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: @IrvinDominin No, I only have jquery, momentjs, and fullcalendar.

Comment: @IrvinDominin here is the fiddle, and... it works on fiddle. [http://jsfiddle.net/fueLwg6u/](http://jsfiddle.net/fueLwg6u/)

Comment: What does your `app.init()` do?

Comment: @Slyvain it declare some click events that aren't related to the calendar, the app.radioButton is related to an other page of my site

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest commenting out large parts of your JavaScript until the only thing left is the full calendar. Then see if it works. If it does, then start uncommenting your JavaScript until you see where the error occurred.

If this doesn't work, then try setting up a straight html file on your server with only full calendar on it. See if the full calendar and its dependencies work as a standalone or if you have a corrupted version or your dependencies are loaded in incorrect order.

Comment: Well, I think I will try to code the onclick function by myself, thank you !